# Upgrading MySQL 5.5 to 8.0, getting different results for query, need help understanding why

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of testing a MySQL upgrade for our application from 5.5 to 8.0.  I've encountered a few queries that return slightly different results and have been able to make it somewhat generic here.  Can someone help explain why the difference in results for this query?

I've noticed that removing the time portion on dates provided in the query nets the same results in both 5.5 and 8.0.

**My generic test table**

```
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| test_date | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+----+------------+
| id | test_date  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2019-01-01 |
|  2 | 2019-01-02 |
|  3 | 2019-01-03 |
|  4 | 2019-01-04 |
|  5 | 2019-01-05 |
|  6 | 2019-01-06 |
|  7 | 2019-01-07 |
|  8 | 2019-01-08 |
|  9 | 2019-01-09 |
| 10 | 2019-01-10 |
| 11 | 2019-01-11 |
| 12 | 2019-01-12 |
| 13 | 2019-01-13 |
| 14 | 2019-01-14 |
| 15 | 2019-01-15 |
| 16 | 2019-01-16 |
| 17 | 2019-01-17 |
| 18 | 2019-01-18 |
| 19 | 2019-01-19 |
| 20 | 2019-01-20 |
| 21 | 2019-01-21 |
| 22 | 2019-01-22 |
| 23 | 2019-01-23 |
| 24 | 2019-01-24 |
| 25 | 2019-01-25 |
| 26 | 2019-01-26 |
| 27 | 2019-01-27 |
| 28 | 2019-01-28 |
| 29 | 2019-01-29 |
| 30 | 2019-01-30 |
| 31 | 2019-01-31 |
+----+------------+
```

**The query that is similar to one from our code base.**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    date_table
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN DAY(test_date) % 2 = 0 THEN test_date
        ELSE DATE_ADD(test_date, INTERVAL - 0 DAY)
    END BETWEEN '2019-01-05 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-15 00:00:00'
```

**MySQL 5.5 Results**

```
+----+------------+
| id | test_date  |
+----+------------+
|  6 | 2019-01-06 |
|  7 | 2019-01-07 |
|  8 | 2019-01-08 |
|  9 | 2019-01-09 |
| 10 | 2019-01-10 |
| 11 | 2019-01-11 |
| 12 | 2019-01-12 |
| 13 | 2019-01-13 |
| 14 | 2019-01-14 |
| 15 | 2019-01-15 |
+----+------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MySQL 8.0 Results**

```
+----+------------+
| id | test_date  |
+----+------------+
|  5 | 2019-01-05 |
|  6 | 2019-01-06 |
|  7 | 2019-01-07 |
|  8 | 2019-01-08 |
|  9 | 2019-01-09 |
| 10 | 2019-01-10 |
| 11 | 2019-01-11 |
| 12 | 2019-01-12 |
| 13 | 2019-01-13 |
| 14 | 2019-01-14 |
| 15 | 2019-01-15 |
+----+------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm expecting the results from both 5.5 and 8.0 to be the same.

Comment: Why not `BETWEEN DATE('2019-01-05 00:00:00') AND DATE('2019-01-15 00:00:00')` assuming that the date strings are not controlled by you?

Comment: This seems like a bug in MySQL 5.x where the promotion from `DATE` type into `TIMESTAMP` is not done correctly. It seems MySQL 8.x got it right, though.

Comment: This is the first time I saw `INTERVAL - 0 DAY`. What exactly does it do?

Comment: Your correct as those would be parameters passed into the query from the user.  This is a very stripped down example that demonstrates the difference. My understanding is that 8.0 results are correct and 5.5 is wrong as it should be inclusive.  Understanding why the difference is happening will greatly help in testing the upgrade and fixing any queries that need changed.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr doesn't add anything.  The integer in the production code comes from another table.

Comment: A related [blog post](https://makandracards.com/makandra/4611-don-t-compare-datetimes-with-date-ranges-in-mysql) might be of interest

Comment: @theimpaler it is `DATETIME`

Comment: Can't say if the issue is throughout 5.x, if at all. Check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5897eb/1/0) using mysql 5.6. it works as expected.

Comment: Different version comparison for this query can be seen at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g4WZ9GU8g5aB6E5ugHsSgk/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Fr0zenFyr for pointing me in the correct direction.  The 5.5 results were indeed wrong with starting date in the range not being returned.  Surrounding the inputted datetime with DATE() returns the correct results.  So the query became

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    date_table
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN DAY(test_date) % 2 = 0 THEN test_date
        ELSE DATE_ADD(test_date, INTERVAL - 0 DAY)
    END BETWEEN DATE('2019-01-05 00:00:00') AND DATE('2019-01-15 00:00:00')
```